# Alternative to popl %esp

Tags: assembly, stack, cpu-registers, x86

In Section 3.4.2, the IA32 popl instruction was described as copying the result from
the top of the stack to the destination register and then incrementing the stack
pointer. So, if we had an instruction of the form popl REG, it would be equivalent
to the code sequence:

```
movl (%esp),REG //Read REG from stack
addl $4,%esp //Increment stack pointer
```

A. In light of analysis done in Problem 4.7, does this code sequence correctly
describe the behavior of the instruction popl %esp? Explain.

B. How could you rewrite the code sequence so that it correctly describes both
the cases where REG is %esp as well as any other register?

problem 4.7:

The following assembly-code function lets us determine the behavior of the instruction
popl %esp for IA32:

```
1 .text
2 .globl poptest
3 poptest:
4 pushl %ebp
5 movl %esp, %ebp
6 pushl $0xabcd Push test value
7 popl %esp Pop to stack pointer
8 movl %esp, %eax Set popped value as return value
9 leave Restore stack and frame pointers
10 ret
```

We find this function always returns 0xabcd. What does this imply about the behavior of popl %esp? What other Y86 instruction would have the exact same behavior?

---

I've been torn on whether or not the code sequence in the first problem correctly describes the behavior of the instruction popl %esp.  At first I thought yes, because it's getting REG from the stack like popl would return the value (I could be wrong on this), and then it increments esp by 4 to remove that instance from the stack.

But then I came across the statement "The popl %esp instruction increments the stack pointer before data at the old top of stack is written into the destination."

If that's the case, then the increment by 4 to esp should have occurred before putting a value into the destination register, making

```
movl (%esp),REG //Read REG from stack
addl $4,%esp //Increment stack pointer
```

an incorrect representation of popl %esp.

Can anyone clarify on whether or not it truly is not correctly describing the behavior or popl %esp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed that's a wrong equivalent for `pop`. Funnily enough, that's the one intel uses in the official instruction set reference too. But at least they do make things clear in the text. A better equivalent code is:

```
leal 4(%esp), %esp ; use lea to preserve flags (thanks to @Sparky)
movl -4(%esp), REG
```

This is however only a logical equivalent, because in reality somebody (such as an interrupt or signal handler) could destroy the value on the stack between the two instructions. The original code doesn't suffer from this problem.

Note that this works for memory operands too, for which the manual says: "*If the ESP register is used as a base register for addressing a destination operand in memory, the POP instruction computes the effective address of the operand after it increments the ESP register.*". We got that case covered as well.

Comment: In addition to what has already been listed as potential issues, the "addl $4, %esp" impacts the eflags register.  To compensate for that, "leal 4(%esp), %esp" can be used in its place.

Comment: @Jester What about for a `push %esp`?

Comment: @bluejamesbond: that would be `movl %esp, -4(%esp); leal -4(%esp), %esp` with the same caveat.